# How to implement multiple anonymous tokens in spring-oauth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Our web-app needs to allow access to our app for multiple unauthenticated users.
In addition to this, at some point, unauthenticated user may enter some kind of secret word, which allows him to access certain pages within our app. Think about documents protected by a password. Unfortunately, I don't see how this could be implemented with our current security layer.

Our security is based on Spring security with Oauth2 implementation. So, in terms of oauth tokens, we need to have different tokens for different anonymous users. As far as I can see, spring generates only one anonymous token and reuses it whenever a client asks to create one.

I wasn't able to find a way to create different anonymous token every time I ask spring to do so. It's either too simple or not possible at all. Am I overlooking something?